# Logging mysql update queries for a specific table

Tags: mysql, logging

Is it possible to log changes only on a specific table using mysql bin log?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve? Can you explain?

Comment: I want to know which UPDATE queries have been executed on table 'abc'

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have just one (or several) databases go into the bin log with [--binlog-do-db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-do-db) on the master.

It is also possible to have the slave replicate only tables that match a certain string with [--replication-wild-do-table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-wild-do-table)